# Sliding window protocol for Packet Link Layer in TinyOS

Tags: networking, operating-system, network-protocols, tinyos

I am searching for the sliding window protocol implementation in TinyOS. While reading the documentation, It looked that some sliding window protocol must be implemented for Packet Link Layer. I wanted to know that which protocol has been implemented and where can I see the implementation for the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sliding window protocol implementation for Host-to-mote communication in Tinyos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748932/sliding-window-protocol-implementation-for-host-to-mote-communication-in-tinyos)